# How do I force doctrine to reload the data from the database?

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, doctrine-odm

I'm using doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 in a symfony2.1 install.

So i'm trying to force my repository to call data from my database instead of using the object it has cached.

```
$audit = $dm->getRepository("WGenSimschoolsBundle:Audit")->findOneById("xxxx");

.... do something somewhere to change the object ....
```

At this point if I call

```
$audit = $dm->getRepository("WGenSimschoolsBundle:Audit")->findOneById("xxxx");
```

The audit data hasn't changed.  It still has the object it originally fetched.  If I try to

```
$dm->refresh($audit)
```

I get the same thing.  Is there anyway for me to go back to the database for the value?

Comment: I think doctrine doesn't use caching by default.. Have you overriden the findOneById method?

Comment: i'm wondering if the php-mongo driver caches the results... i couldn't find anything in the doctrine documentation that talked about caching either

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Have you flushed your changes to the `$audit` object?

```
$audit = $dm->getRepository("WGenSimschoolsBundle:Audit")->findOneById("xxxx");
//do something somewhere to change the object
$dm->flush();
```

---

Every time you do a `findBy(...)` or `findOneBy(...)` it actually fetches a new document from the DB. (you should see the query in the Symfony profiler)

With a find() instead, it will fetch the document from his internal proxy cache.
The Documents stay in the proxy cache until you call the `$dm->clear()` method.

Comment: In my case (see my answer), the `findOneBy` did use cache too ! I had to use `$em->clear();`

Comment: Doctrine ORM has a "Query cache", that ODM doesn't (actually) have, are you sure your result didn't came from that cache?

Comment: Clear remove all entities saved in the cache, so if a the user is persisted (for exemple), doctrine will throw an error because it does not know this existing user and doctrine propose to apply a "Cascade persist" in order to add it. But the user already exist. So this solution is not effective in that case. According to me, the best solution is to use `$entityManager->refresh($entity);` in order to force reload the entity directly from the database.

Answer (score 46):

This worked for me:

```
$doc = $this->documentManager->getRepository('MyBundle:MyDoc')->find($id);

/* ... in the meanwhile another external process is doing some changes to the object ...*/
$doc = $this->documentManager->getRepository('MyBundle:MyDoc')->find($id); // Perhaps this is not useful
$this->documentManager->refresh($doc);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the refresh option - been looking for that for ages

Comment: Yes... you're answer worked for me too, instead of that with more votes.

Comment: This should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 29):

Adding to the previous answers, I was searching how to refresh the database of an `Entity`, not of a `Document` but the solution was close. I'm posting it here for others stumbling on this page with the same problem.

In one of my functional tests, I was using two times the same query:

```
$em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$user = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('email' => 'james.bond@secure.gov.co.uk'));
echo "Old hash: ".$user->getPassword() . "\n";
// result: 8bb6118f8fd6935ad0876a3be34a717d32708ffd
```

Then the tests goes through a process of changing the password. I then re-queried the user to compare if the password hash had changed with the *same* query:

```
$user = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('email' => 'james.bond@secure.gov.co.uk'));
echo "New hash: ".$user->getPassword() . "\n";
// result: 8bb6118f8fd6935ad0876a3be34a717d32708ffd # Same !
```

The problem was that even though the tested controller updated the hash, the entity manager had the entity in **cache**.

So, the solution was to add the following between the two queries:

```
$em->clear();
```

And now, the password hash changed between queries ! Yay !

Comment: Why to clear the whole cache instead of just reloading/refresh the entity object from data source?

Comment: Because at the time of writing this, I didn't know there was that option. Maybe there's a more granular way the flush/refresh.

Answer (score 9):

You can use method refresh :

```
$post; # modified
$entityManager->refresh();
$post; # reset from db
```

Comment: This works by accident only. `refresh` reloads a single entity from the data source, you're omitting a required parameter in your example. You should call `$em->clear()` to detach all entities instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you deal with related entities, if you modify the related entities and save them through the parent object, you will have to add an option cascade={"detach"} for the detach to be effective.

For example, let's say you want to update a list of Friends on a Person object, by adding new objects to the list, removing some of them and updating some existing ones. You're going to have

```
$em->flush();
$em->detach($entity);
```

And in your Person entity make sure to update your friends relation :

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Somewhere\PeopleBundle\Entity\Person", mappedBy="person", cascade={"detach"})
private $friends;
```

Comment: Is this expected Behaviour?

Comment: $em->detach($entity); is depricated. Use $em->refresh($entity);

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$dm->getUnitOfWork()->clear('WGenSimschoolsBundle:Audit');
```

Comment: this didn't work for me.  I'm still getting the same object back

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `EntityManager#clear()`. See [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map).