# doctrine 2 entity is not filled with childs element

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

Within my database I have two related tables.

AppBooking

AppBookingService

AppBookingService has a foreign key to AppBooking

I use this method to make an insertion in both the first and second table.

```
public function bookingExecute($data){
    try{
        $this->em->beginTransaction();
        $appBooking = $this->_fillAppBooking($data);
        $this->em->persist($appBooking);
        if(array_key_exists("appService",$data) && is_array($data['appService']) && count($data['appService']) > 0){
            foreach($data['appService'] as  $bookingService){
                $appBookingService = $this->_fillAppBookingService($bookingService,$appBooking);
                $this->em->persist($appBookingService);
                $this->em->flush();
            }
        }
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->commit();
        return $appBooking;
    }catch (\Exception $ex){
        $this->em->rollback();
        throw new BookingException("",BookingError::BOOKING_QUERY_ERROR);
    }
}
```

The data is written correctly

After that, in the same http request, I invoke the method below in order to have AppBooking Service data within my entity

```
$appBooking = $this->bookingService->findOne($id);
```

The problem that the AppBooking entity I get does not contain AppBookingService

The method

```
$appBooking->getServices()->count()
```

returns 0

If I make the same call in another http request I get the desired result.

It is as if doctrine did not update the entity in that same request

This is a part of AppBooking

```
/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBookingService", mappedBy="idBooking")
 */
private $services;

public function __construct() {
    $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

This is part of AppBookingService

```
/**
 * @var \Entity\Entity\AppBooking
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Entity\AppBooking", inversedBy="services")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ID_BOOKING", referencedColumnName="ID_BOOKING", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $idBooking;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when running

```
$appBooking = $this->bookingService->findOne($id);
```

The entity  is fetched from his internal proxy cache. No database query is executed to get the entity `s data. The same is true for its already loaded associations. The **Proxy cache** is valid during the execution of a http request.

To solve this, you either have to update the `$services` Collection manually or **[refresh](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_refresh)** the entity.

```
$this->em->refresh($appBooking);
```

> Refreshes the persistent state of an entity from the database, overriding any local changes that have not yet been persisted.

You can also **[clear](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_clear)** the entire entity manager cache **before** calling the findOne() method.

```
$this->em->clear();
```

> Clears the EntityManager. All entities that are currently managed by this EntityManager become detached.

**References**

- [How do I force doctrine to reload the data from the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761833/how-do-i-force-doctrine-to-reload-the-data-from-the-database)